# Which rim to buy

Tags: tires, nissan, altima, wheels

I'm looking to replace rim for one of the wheels of my car (Nissan Altima 06). The wheel specs - 245/45 R18. (Different from the ones that come with the original car)

The rim looks like this - [image]

I found similar rims online on [ebay](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Brand-New-18-034-Alloy-Wheel-Rim-for-2004-2005-2006-Nissan-Maxima-/280728949429), which looked exactly like the one I have; but then I stumbled upon this [tire size calculator](http://www.tyresizecalculator.com/tyre-wheel-calculators/tyre-size-for-rim-size-width-calculator). After playing around with this calculator, now, I'm not sure how important is the rim width, and what width would be appropriate in my case. I'd appreciate any help in this regard.

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered having it repaired rather than replaced? I had two of my rims on my '14 Honda Accord repaired, and they look just like new.

Comment: When replacing a rim, the 3 most important things are: matching bolt pattern, the hole in the middle of the rim's size, and the rim diameter.  The rim width and lug nut style are secondary characteristics.  If you just need a rim and don't care about looks, here is an [excellent list](http://www.ezaccessory.com/Thread_Size_and_Bolt_Pattern_Applicatoin_Guide_s/12.htm) of wheel info.  You can find another vehicle with the same specs as yours which gives you more buying options..

Answer (score 1):

The width should be the same width as the one you are replacing. If you don't, it will mess with the stability of your vehicle, how the tire wears, and could possibly (down the line) cause tire failure ... That's probably a little over dramatic, but a possibility. This is, of course if you are just replacing one wheel. If you are replacing them all, width is dependent upon the width of the tire and what it can support in rim width.